# The docker host is currently not running

Tags: docker, minikube

From Ubuntu 18.0.4 i am trying to run next command on terminal

> eval $(minikube docker-env)

but unfortunately i got next message

[image]

and when i checked docker status i see it's running and active

[image]

**Note:**
I started minikube cluster using next command

> minikube start -p ClusterName

not using

> minikube start

any idea how i can solve this problem?

Comment: minikube has its own docker daemon . so first start minikube

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of terminal output, instead copy and paste into a code block.

Comment: @AbhishekDK but this doesn't make minikube docker sharable with this new cluster which used after -p argument, so how i can run "minikube start -p ClusterName" with its own docker instance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you started your minikube instance with

```sh
minikube start -p ClusterName
```

Then you'll have to put the profile name for each command

```sh
minikube docker-env -p ClusterName
```

So you finally can run next command to get it work

```sh
> eval $(minikube docker-env -p YourClusterName)
```